# Can i view sent chat messages (images / text) for the sender in RecyclerView offline?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, android-recyclerview

I want to view the chat messages instantly offline for the sender, before retrieving data from the firestore. I want to make the insertion for the sender side RecyclerView just like whatsapp style.
Below, the retrieving process from firestore, data insertion in data class and chat adapter.
If anyone can help me to make it work,
Thank you...

Sending data to firestore

```
imgSend.setOnClickListener {
            if (mSaveImageUri != null) {
                finish()
                val reference = storage.reference.child("Chats").child(senderRoom)
                    .child("Image Messages").child(senderUid)
                val reference2 = storage.reference.child("Chats").child(receiverRoom)
                    .child("Image Messages").child(senderUid)
                reference.putFile(mSaveImageUri!!).addOnCompleteListener { task ->
                    reference2.putFile(mSaveImageUri!!)
                    if (task.isSuccessful) {
                        reference.downloadUrl.addOnSuccessListener { uri ->
                            imgMsg = uri.toString()
                            val date = Date()
                            val calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
                            val day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)
                            var currentDay = ""
                            when (day) {
                                Calendar.SUNDAY -> {
                                    currentDay = "Sunday"
                                }
                                Calendar.MONDAY -> {
                                    currentDay = "Monday"
                                }
                                Calendar.TUESDAY -> {
                                    currentDay = "Tuesday"
                                }
                                Calendar.WEDNESDAY -> {
                                    currentDay = "Wednesday"
                                }
                                Calendar.THURSDAY -> {
                                    currentDay = "Thursday"
                                }
                                Calendar.FRIDAY -> {
                                    currentDay = "Friday"
                                }
                                Calendar.SATURDAY -> {
                                    currentDay = "Saturday"
                                }
                            }
                            val id = firestore.collection("Chats").document().id
                            val imageMsg = hashMapOf("message" to imgMsg, "senderId" to senderUid, "date" to calendar,
                                "time" to date, "day" to currentDay, "seen" to "false", "type" to "photo")
                            firestore.collection("Chats").document(senderRoom)
                                .collection("messages").document(id)
                                .set(imageMsg).addOnSuccessListener {
                                    firestore.collection("Chats").document(receiverRoom)
                                        .collection("messages").document(id)
                                        .set(imageMsg).addOnSuccessListener { }
                                        .addOnFailureListener {
                                            Toast.makeText(
                                                applicationContext,
                                                "Failed",
                                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                                            ).show()
                                        }
                                }
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Please save your image first", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }
```

Retrieving data from firestore

```
private fun setDataToAdapter() {
        firestore.collection("Chats").document(senderRoom!!).collection("messages").orderBy("time")
            .addSnapshotListener { value, _ ->
                if (!value?.isEmpty!!) {
                    messages.clear()
                    for (document in value.documents) {
                        val coMsg = document.data?.get("message").toString()
                        val coId = document.data?.get("senderId").toString()
                        val msgId = document.id
                        //Using Date
                        // Get Calendar
                        val calendarMap = document.data?.get("date") as Map<*, *>
                        val curTimestamp = calendarMap["time"] as com.google.firebase.Timestamp
                        val millis =
                            curTimestamp.seconds * 1000 + curTimestamp.nanoseconds / 1000000
                        val ss = SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a", Locale.getDefault())
                        val netCal = Date(millis)
                        val msgTime = ss.format(netCal).toString()
                        // Get Day
                        val chatDay = document.data?.get("day").toString()
                        // Get Full Date
                        val fullDateStamp = calendarMap["time"] as com.google.firebase.Timestamp
                        val dateInMillis =
                            fullDateStamp.seconds * 1000 + fullDateStamp.nanoseconds / 1000
                        val sdf = SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy", Locale.getDefault())
                        val netAllDate = Date(dateInMillis)
                        val fullDate = sdf.format(netAllDate).toString()
                        val type = document.data?.get("type").toString()
                        val coMsgT = SingleChatData(coMsg, coId, msgId, msgTime, chatDay, fullDate, type)
                        messages.add(coMsgT)
                    }
                    if (!firstScrollDone) {
                        recyclerView.post { // Call smooth scroll
                            recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(adapter.itemCount - 1)
                        }
                    }
                    //firstScrollDone = true
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
                }
            }
    }
```

Chat Adapter ViewHolder

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val currentMsg = messages[position]
        //Glide.with(holder.itemView.context).load(R.drawable.me_p)
        if (holder.javaClass == SentMsgViewHolder::class.java){
            val viewHolder = holder as SentMsgViewHolder
            when (currentMsg.type) {
                "photo" -> {
                    viewHolder.binding.sentTxtMsgL.visibility = View.GONE
                    viewHolder.binding.sentImgLandL.visibility = View.GONE
                    viewHolder.binding.sentRecordL.visibility = View.GONE
                    viewHolder.binding.sentImgL.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                    viewHolder.binding.dateSeenImgS.text = currentMsg.time
                    Glide.with(holder.itemView.context).load(R.drawable.me_p).into(holder.binding.sentImg)
                    Glide.with(holder.itemView.context).load(currentMsg.message).into(holder.binding.sentImg)
                    viewHolder.binding.sentImgL.setOnClickListener {
                        OneImageActivity.start(holder.itemView.context as Activity, holder.binding.sentImg,
                            holder.binding.dateTimeTxtS, Bundle().apply {
                                putString("img", currentMsg.message)
                                putString("date", currentMsg.time)
                            })
                    }
                }
                "text" -> {
                    viewHolder.binding.sentImgL.visibility = View.GONE
                    viewHolder.binding.sentImgLandL.visibility = View.GONE
                    viewHolder.binding.sentRecordL.visibility = View.GONE
                    viewHolder.binding.sentTxtMsgL.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                    viewHolder.binding.sentMsg.text = currentMsg.message
                    viewHolder.binding.dateTimeTxtS.text = currentMsg.time
                    //viewHolder.binding.dateTimeTxt.text = currentMsg.time
                    viewHolder.binding.sentMsgL.isLongClickable = true
                    viewHolder.binding.sentMsgL.isClickable = true
                    viewHolder.binding.sentMsgL.isFocusable = true
                    viewHolder.binding.sentMsgL.isActivated = true
                    viewHolder.binding.sentMsgL.setOnLongClickListener {
                        currentMsg.messageId.let { it ->
                        }
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                        true
                    }
                }
                "record" -> {
                    viewHolder.binding.sentImgL.visibility = View.GONE
                    viewHolder.binding.sentImgLandL.visibility = View.GONE
                    viewHolder.binding.sentRecordL.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                    viewHolder.binding.sentTxtMsgL.visibility = View.GONE
                    GlobalScope.launch {
                        viewHolder.binding.sentRecord.setAudio(currentMsg.message)
                    }
                }
            }
            holder.itemView.setOnLongClickListener {
                if (getSelectedItem().size == 0) {
                    itemsData?.add(SelectedItemsData(currentMsg))
                    viewHolder.binding.selectedMarkS?.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                    currentMsg.selected = true
                    selectedShared.setData("false", "0")
                    incDecNum(true)
                    showChosenToolbar(true, false)
                }
                true
            }
            holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
                if (getSelectedItem().size > 0) {
                    if (currentMsg.selected) {
                        itemsData?.remove(SelectedItemsData(currentMsg))
                        viewHolder.binding.selectedMarkS?.visibility = View.GONE
                        currentMsg.selected = false
                        incDecNum(false)
                        if (getSelectedItem().size == 0) {
                            showChosenToolbar(false, true)
                            //selectedShared.setData("false")
                        }
                    } else {
                        itemsData?.add(SelectedItemsData(currentMsg))
                        viewHolder.binding.selectedMarkS?.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                        currentMsg.selected = true
                        incDecNum(true)
                        //selectedShared.setData("true")
                        showChosenToolbar(true, false)
                    }
                }
            }
            if (currentMsg.selected) {
                viewHolder.binding.selectedMarkS?.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            } else {
                viewHolder.binding.selectedMarkS?.visibility = View.GONE
            }
        } else {
            val viewHolder = holder as ReceivedMsgViewHolder
            when (currentMsg.type) {
                "photo" -> {
                    viewHolder.binding.receivedImgL.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                    viewHolder.binding.receivedTxtMsgL.visibility = View.GONE
                    //holder.binding.receivedImg.setImageURI(currentMsg.urlImg?.toUri())
                    viewHolder.binding.dateSeenImgR.text = currentMsg.time
                    viewHolder.binding.receivedRecordL.visibility = View.GONE
                    Glide.with(holder.itemView.context).load(currentMsg.message).into(holder.binding.receivedImg)
                    viewHolder.binding.receivedImgL.setOnClickListener {
                        OneImageActivity.start(holder.itemView.context as Activity, holder.binding.receivedImg,
                            holder.binding.dateTimeTxtR, Bundle().apply {
                                putString("img", currentMsg.message)
                                putString("date", currentMsg.time)
                            })
                    }
                }
                "text" -> {
                    viewHolder.binding.receivedImgL.visibility = View.GONE
                    viewHolder.binding.receivedTxtMsgL.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                    viewHolder.binding.receivedRecordL.visibility = View.GONE
                    viewHolder.binding.receivedMsg.text = currentMsg.message
                    viewHolder.binding.dateTimeTxtR.text = currentMsg.time
                    //viewHolder.binding.dateTimeTxtR.text = currentMsg.time
                }
                "record" -> {
                    viewHolder.binding.receivedImgL.visibility = View.GONE
                    viewHolder.binding.receivedRecordL.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                    viewHolder.binding.receivedTxtMsgL.visibility = View.GONE
                    GlobalScope.launch {
                        viewHolder.binding.receivedRecord.setAudio(currentMsg.message)
                    }
                }
            }
            holder.itemView.setOnLongClickListener {
                if (getSelectedItem().size == 0) {
                    itemsData?.add(SelectedItemsData(currentMsg))
                    viewHolder.binding.selectedMarkR?.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                    currentMsg.selected = true
                    incDecNum(true)
                    selectedShared.setData("true", "1")
                    showChosenToolbar(true, false)
                }
                true
            }
            holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
                if (getSelectedItem().size > 0) {
                    if (currentMsg.selected) {
                        itemsData?.remove(SelectedItemsData(currentMsg))
                        viewHolder.binding.selectedMarkR?.visibility = View.GONE
                        currentMsg.selected = false
                        selectedShared.setData("true", (selectedShared.getNum().toInt() - 1).toString())
                        incDecNum(false)
                        if (getSelectedItem().size == 0) {
                            showChosenToolbar(false, true)
                            selectedShared.setData("false", "0")
                        }
                    } else {
                        itemsData?.add(SelectedItemsData(currentMsg))
                        viewHolder.binding.selectedMarkR?.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                        currentMsg.selected = true
                        incDecNum(true)
                        selectedShared.setData("true", (selectedShared.getNum().toInt() + 1).toString())
                        showChosenToolbar(true, false)
                    }
                }
            }
            if (currentMsg.selected) {
                viewHolder.binding.selectedMarkR?.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            } else {
                viewHolder.binding.selectedMarkR?.visibility = View.GONE
            }
            val isSelected = selectedShared.getBool()
        }
    }
```

Data Class

```
class SingleChatData{
    var senderId: String?= null
    var message: String?= null
    var messageId: String?= null
    var time: String?= null
    var chatDay: String?= null
    var fullDate: String?= null
    var type: String?= null
    var selected: Boolean = false
    var msgId2: String?= null

    constructor(message: String?, senderId: String?, messageId: String?,time: String, chatDay: String?,
                fullDate: String?, type: String?){
        this.message = message
        this.senderId = senderId
        this.messageId = messageId
        this.time = time
        this.chatDay = chatDay
        this.fullDate = fullDate
        this.type = type
        //this.msgId2 = msgId2
    }
}
```

Comment: If you encounter problems, it's best to create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when posting a question. You posted almost **300** (three hundred) lines of code for this issue. That's a lot for people to parse and try to debug online. Please edit your question and isolate the problem, in that way you increase your chances of being helped. Please take a moment and read [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Besides that, I'm having a hard time understanding what the problem is.
What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?